# Can I query more than 1 AD domain in one query?

Tags: active-directory

I have a program that gets login information from Active Directory, I use an LDAP URL simular to this (to query mycompany.com):

```
LDAP://OU=MYCO,DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=COM
```

Is there a way to query `mycompany.com` and `yourcompany.com` (not in the same forest) using the same URL? Or do I have to rewrite the program to query them serially? (I am trying to avoid a rewrite.)

EDIT: As I suspected, I would have to query them seperately. Outside of the evil EE, I didn't find anything to confirm this.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't interrogate two different domains in the same LDAP query.  You need to work around this programatically

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
Misread question. I believe you'll have to query them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your domains are in the same AD forest, you'll want to query the global catalog to do a cross-domain query.  Changing the query URI to GC:// instead of LDAP:// indicates you want to specifically do a global catalog query.  LDAP will go straight to a domain controller of the specific domain which won't necessarily know anything about the other domains you are interested in.

```
GC://dc=domain,dc=com/....
```

Keep in mind, though, that the global catalog only has a subset of the attributes available in the AD schema so you might have to go out to the domains themselves anyway.  Here's a list of [**AD global attributes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675094%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Note that it doesn't look like the domains in your question would be in the same forest.